# What does the word 「部下となし」 mean?

Tags: words, renyōkei

Here is the sentence including the word.

> そのドヤ街｛がい｝に住む｛すむ｝子｛こ｝どもたちをそそのかしてかれらを**部下{ぶか}となし**

Comment: Are you sure that's where the sentence ends? This looks like the continuative form (連用形) of the verb なす; if it is, there should probably be something following it.

Comment: @senshin Yes. Here is the next sentence.

付近を巡回する警官らの再三の注意にもかかわらず

Comment: Japanese has punctuation, just like English. You should include it in your questions. Knowing whether なし is followed by a comma or a period is valuable when your potential answerers need to guess the context that you don't include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「部下となし」 does not exist as a single idiom or set phrase -- as you should be able to tell from the paucity of Google search results such a query will bring up.

Instead, the なし here is the continuative form (連用形{れんようけい}) of the verb 為{な}す (to make/turn in to):

"He tempts the kids who live in that flophouse area, and turns them into his subordinates."

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I have another questions.  1) What does the 「と」do in this sentence? Should it be 「を」 instead?
2)If the なし conjugated from 連用形, why does the verb not end with 「て」?

Comment: 1) Here, the particle と marks 部下 as the indirect object of なす (whereas the direct object かれら is indicated by を). Most verbs use に to mark their indirect objects, but なす can be somewhat irregular like that. 2) attaching て like that is customary in (casual) spoken Japanese, but in written (and some formal spoken) Japanese using the bare 連用形 is (stylistically) preferable.